# Why univocity's CsvParser throwing error when use LocalDate as the datatype for POJO and How to reslove it?

Tags: java, string, csv, localdate, univocity

I am using Univocity's CSVParser to read csv file. My POJO look something like this.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import com.univocity.parsers.annotations.NullString;
import com.univocity.parsers.annotations.Parsed;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class TempClass {

    @Parsed(field = "A")
    private int a;

    @Parsed(field = "B")
    private String b;

    @Parsed(field = "C")
    private LocalDate c;
}
```

My csv file look something like this:-

```
A,B,C
1,"Hi","2019-01-12"
2,"Hey","2019-01-13"
3,"Hello","2019-01-14"
```

Now when I try to read this file using CsvParser, it throws error saying `Unable to set value '2019-01-12' of type 'java.lang.String' to field attribute 'c'`.

Here I am guessing it is throwing error because it can not implicitly convert `String` to `LocalDate`. If that is the case then How can it able to convert `String` to `int`?

Is there way to solve the error `Unable to set value '2019-01-12' of type 'java.lang.String' to field attribute 'c'`?(without changeing data type of `TempClass.c`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Univocity-parsers is still built on Java 6. `LocalDate` is not directly supported out of the box, but can to provide a conversion yourself. Something like:

```
public class LocalDateFormatter implements  Conversion<String, LocalDate> {

    private DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    public LocalDateFormatter(String... args) {
        String pattern = "dd MM yyyy";
        if(args.length > 0){
            pattern = args[0];
        }
        this.formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate execute(String input) {
        return LocalDate.parse(input, formatter);
    }

    @Override
    public String revert(LocalDate input) {
        return formatter.format(input);
    }
}
```

Then annotate your fields with `@Convert` and provide your conversion class:"

```
@Parsed(field = "C")
@Convert(conversionClass = LocalDateFormatter.class, args = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate c;
```

The next version (3.0.0) is coming soon with support for this and a lot more.

Hope this helps.